# Trying to make directories using brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell

Maybe this is a pretty silly question. I'm a beginner at bash scripting and I'm not able to properly while trying to execute the command.

```
#!bin/bash
noise={5,10,15}dB
mkdir $(echo $noise)
```

I want to create 3 directories 5dB,10dB, and 15dB in a bash script where {5,10,15}dB is given as a positional argument. The script doesn't perform the brace expansion and gives a folder {5,10,15}dB. Can anyone help me??

Comment: if you intend to use `$noise` elsewhere, maybe your are looking for array not bash expansion.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store it in a variable first. Braces don't expand on the right hand side of variable assignment anyway so your variable is becoming literally `{5,10,15}dB`.

You can just do:

```
mkdir {5,10,15}dB
```

Additionally there is no need to echo a variable inside command substitution, all that is doing is expanding the contents of the variable so:

```
mkdir $(echo $noise)
```

Is no different than:

```
mkdir $noise
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the expansion order that confused you. Bash performs them in a specific order, and it's the brace expansion that comes first, followed by the variable expansion. This is why the brace expansion did not work in your example.

You can use `eval` to force bash into performing the expansion:

```
noise={5,10,15}dB
# BAD IDEA, FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES ONLY
eval mkdir $noise
```

However, generally it's bad practice because if there's some malicious code inside `$noise`, it will be executed, as well.

As @Archemar points out in a comment, using an [array](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) might be a better idea, e.g.

```
noise=(5 10 15)
mkdir "${arr[@]/%/dB}"
```

---

If you're passing the directory names from the command line, there should be no issues with brace expansion because it will be done by the interactive shell when you call the script. In other words, the following will work:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "$@"

$ ./script.sh {5,10,15}dB
```

Comment: I see, I guess I'll try using an array, but actually noise variable is initialised through command line argument. But I'll see if I can use it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AnubhabGhosh In that case there should be no problem with the brace expansion at all, see the updated answer.