# apt install: difference between regex and var=regex

Tags: apt, regular-expression, variable

I currently have a problem in a script with apt install and don't understand why.

Whats the difference between:

```
# works fine
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}
```

and

```
var="gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}"
apt install $var

[...]
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}'
E: Regex compilation error - Invalid content of \{\}
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}'
E: Unable to locate package gstreamer1.0-{omx,alsa}
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gstreamer1.0-{omx,alsa}'
E: Regex compilation error - Invalid content of \{\}
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gstreamer1.0-{omx,alsa}'
```

kind regards

Comment: Looks like brace expansion and not regex.

Comment: That's not a regex - it's a brace expansion. Brace expansion is not performed on the RHS of an assignment (even when unquoted). See related [Trying to make directories using brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569849/trying-to-make-directories-using-brace-expansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) and not regex.  Brace expansion doesn't work inside quotes or when a variable is assigned/expanded.

What your first command is doing:

```
apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

What your second command is doing:

```
apt install "gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly}"
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: At least in bash, one could use a brace expansion to construct an array I think, like `var=( gstreamer1.0-plugins-{bad,base,good,ugly} )` then use that as `apt install "${var[@]}"`

Comment: @steeldriver works great, thanks a lot!